# Where to store my index.html and index view for a non-static Django homepage

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm creating a Django project and currently have 3 apps (products, questions and choices) - I've got them all functioning separately/together as I'd like and am using namespaces and include as part of my urls (my urls.py given below...)

```
### urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^products/', include('products.urls', namespace='products')),
    url(r'^questions/', include('questions.urls', namespace='questions')),
    url(r'^choices/', include('choices.urls', namespace='choices')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Now I'm looking to add an index page (accessible at localhost:8000/) that will allow me to access all models created. I'm happy with my views.py...

```
## views.py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from products.models import Product
from questions.models import Question
from choices.models import Choice


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_product_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['questions'] = Question.objects.all()
        context['choices'] = Choice.objects.all()
        return context
```

What I'd like to know is, what is the most sensible combination of urls.py entry, positioning of views.py and location of index.html to allow me to show a combination of my models on the landing page?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create another app (I tend to name it `home`).  That way, your home app can import models from products, questions and choices.

#### App layout

```
home/urls.py
home/views.py
home/templates/index.html
```

Include your home urls just like your other apps (but don't use a prefix)

```
url(r'^', include('home.urls', namespace='home')),
```

Comment: Thanks for this - seems sensible and have managed to get it work using almost exactly this answer (have the template in home/templates/home/index.html but other than that - exact). Cheers!